# AvalonDock 2.0 with Prism 4 Region Adapter

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, avalondock

I have been playing around with this question.

[AvalonDock with Prism Region Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905238/avalondock-with-prism-region-adapter)

Where someone is trying to add a prism region adapter. It sort of works but as soon as i float the panel the content vanishes and goes completely black.

Is this an error from me?
I have also tried using regions directly under the dockingmanager and they can be updated but not when the region is already floated. Is this expected behaviour? ie. Can a floated region be updated?

I also tried the variation from vaccano here: http://avalondock.codeplex.com/discussions/358632

But i don't see how the regionmanager.setregionname() method creates a region which can be updated. ie. it is nowhere to be found in my region collection.

Any help with any or all of these much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted a sample application that shows a way to integrate AvalonDock 2.0 with PRISM 4.1. Please follow the discussion:
http://avalondock.codeplex.com/discussions/390255
Here you can download the sample project:
http://avalondock.codeplex.com/releases/view/92210
Ado

Comment: Thanks I was away from here quite a while but had seen your discussion...finally giving you credit !

Comment: @adospace these links are dead :\